# Javascript, help understand how parentheses works in code

Tags: javascript

my question is about parentheses () in Javascript code, for example in the snippet of code below, are the parentheses 'grouping operators'? or something else? if there are 2 or more sets of parentheses (), which set of () is evaluated first in the same line? have googled but can't find much about this. Although I understand most of this little program, I am struggling to understand lines 5 + 6 as I don't understand this aforementioned parentheses issue, thanks very much for any help!

```
<script>
function playAudio(audioNumber) {
  var audio = document.getElementById('sound' + audioNumber);
  audio.play();
  var nonPlaying = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  nonPlaying.splice(notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber), 1); // line 5
  nonPlaying.forEach(function (id) {  // line 6
    document.getElementById('sound' + id).pause();
    document.getElementById('sound' + id).currentTime = 0;
  });
};

</script>
```

Comment: The parentheses in your code snippet denote the start and end of functions.  If you don't know even this, then Stack Overflow isn't the best place for you yet and you should seek out a good JS tutorial.

Comment: I'm interested to know how line 5 is evaluated, for example is (audioNumber) evaluated first on line 5 and why? Perhaps someone else has more constructive input :)

Comment: Evaluation is inside out, meaning that `indexOf` would be evaluated first, then the result of this would be used to evaluate `splice`.

Comment: Here is a good for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: Thanks Tim Bieg, that's exactly the sort of thing I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 5, the parenthesis follow standard order of operation, just like in math. For

```
nonPlaying.splice(notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber), 1);
```

The call to `indexOf` is inside of the argument list (parentheses) of `splice`, so it's evaluated first. This makes sense though since `indexOf` must be evaluated before its return can be passed to `splice`.

---

To answer "which set of () is evaluated first in the same line", that depends on how they're used. In

```
document.getElementById('sound' + id).pause();
```

The line is evaluated left to right, although that has little to do with the parentheses. In

```
a().b()
```

`a` must be evaluated first since `b` is a method of `a`. The [*operator associativity*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) of `.` defines the order.

---

The only other use is as the parameter list to the anonymous function:

```
function (id) {...}
```

Which is a bit of a special case. I don't think there's a situation where you would have nested parentheses in a parameter list; even with destructuring since JS doesn't use `()` to define any structures.

Comment: Thanks Carcigenicate, that looks very helpful - I had come across these concepts already, before i posted this question - in my research about this, operator associativity, inner () evaluated first etc, it's just joining it all together. Will study your reply